# Can I setup & use a google play account for free & paid items only using gift cards?

Tags: google-play-store

Is it possible to setup a google play account without a credit card, using only gift cards (this is possible on apple), which will allow me to download free and paid apps & music from the play store?

I'm in the uk if that helps,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it not be possible?

- You can setup a Google account without any payment method attached.
- You can add giftcard codes to your playstore account.
- Giftcards can be used to pay for apps.

Watson combined: Setting up an account with no payment, add a giftcard to it – and with that should be able to pay for apps (and use them, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Google account indeed does not require you to have your credit card linked to use Google app store. You can just set up your account, log in and download the apps without problems. If you do want to buy certain apps using gift cards, you can do that without any problems, redeem your gift card and you are good to go. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, both your and @Izzy 's answers were equally useful, so I accepted the one posted earlier, and upvoted them both